# Flutter TextField formatting like Paypal

Tags: flutter, format, textfield

I want to implement a Textfield, where initially is displayed "--,--".
If i press 1, then it should be "--,-1" and so on. So it is basically an int but the text is formatted. This kind of input is also used by paypal if you want to send your friends money. You also can navigate there. I didnt found any package or question.

Maybe someone of you guys know how to solve this issue.

Best Regards,
Colin

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a default string to `--.--` and set it as the default value with TextEditingController.

```dart
late TextEditingController _cont;

@override
initState(){
    super.initState();
    _cont = TextEditingController()
}

_cont.text = '--.--'

//...

TextField(
    controller: _cont,
    onChanged: (val) {
                   _cont.text = _cont.text.substring(0,5 - val.length) + val
               }
)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but this doesn't work for me. It just buggs and throws errors with what you got in the onChanged.

Comment: @ColinSchneider May I know the error.